# Communicate error message from virtual table implementation

Tags: c, sqlite

Is there any way to communicate an error message from methods in a Sqlite [virtual table](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) implementation.

For example, in my implementation of xConnect, I have some code to process the argv array.  If this code detects an error, it can return SQLITE_MISUSE, or some other error code, but I don't see a good way to communicate something more human readable, e.g. "filename argument required".

I tried calling [sqlite3_log()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/log.html) inside of my xConnect, but it doesn't seem to cause a message to be shown to the end user when he/she is using the sqlite3 command line utility.

Answer (score 0):

The only function that can set the error string is `sqlite3Error`, which is declared as `SQLITE_PRIVATE`.

You cannot call this function unless you redefine `SQLITE_PRIVATE` when compiling SQLite.